# Constructores en clases abstractas Java

Tags: java

mi duda es:

¿Cuál es la finalidad de tener constructores en las clases abstractas si las clases hijas NO pueden instanciar de ella?

Saludos.

Comment: En esta cuestión hablan de lo que preguntas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/228/clase-abstracta-con-constructor/231

Answer (score 0):

En una clase abstracta, el constructor que es en una subclase puede llamar el constructor. [Una respuesta en StackOverflow (ingles)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/260755/2805120) tiene un ejemplo.

Por qué? Para imponer restricciones en subclases y ese fue el decisión de diseñadores de Java. Por favor nota que las subclases no son requeridas a llamar el constructor, pero es posible ser conveniente.