# if y else if, java en android studio

Tags: java, android

Quería saber cómo puedo hacer para que si `response` es igual al `id` de Facebook, vaya a un `activity`, y que de lo contrario vaya a otro `activity`.

Cuando intento con:

```
if (profil.getId().toString() == response)
```

y corro mi aplicación, me sale un cartel de que se detuvo la aplicación.
¿Alguien me podría ayudar por favor?

Código:

```
  public class MainoRegistro extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maino_registro);

             final Profile profil = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            final String URL = "http://midominio.com/consulta.php?facebookid="+profil.getId().toString();
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    response = response.replaceAll("\"","").replace("]","").replace("[","");

            if (response == profil.getId()){
                Registrado();

            }else {
                registro();
            }


                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                    IrPantallaLogin();
                }
            });
            queue.add(stringRequest);
        }

private void registro() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainoRegistro.this,Registro.class);
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
}

private void Registrado() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainoRegistro.this,MainActivity.class);
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

---

ahora que coloco el metodo .trim() se detiene la app y en el logcat me dice lo siguiente:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.mathiastoledo.talkit/com.mathiastoledo.tal‌​kit.MainoRegistro}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String com.facebook.Profile.getId()' on a null object
>   reference

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir lo que te aparece en el `logcat` cuando te sucede esto para poder ayudarte mejor?

Comment: @sstan Hola, es una parte del problema, la otra parte del problema es que no cambia de Activity por alguna razón, pero necesita agregar el OP más info.

Comment: Donde tratas de abrir la Activity? podrías agregar esa parte y el LogCat con el problema @MathiasToledo

Comment: @Elenasys: ok, gracias por aclarar. Retiro el voto, pero dejo el comentario como referencia.

Comment: Grracias a todos jajaja, perdon por ser tan cavernicola

Comment: Esta pregunta no debió ser cerrada como duplicado ya que eran varios detalles los cuales impedían se realizara el Intent, y no solo la comparación de Strings... en fin.⤜(ʘ_ʘ)⤏

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema visible parece ser la comparación de los dos strings, no debes realizarlo mediante el operador  `==` :

`if (profil.getId().toString() == response)`

Debes comparar los strings mediante el método `equals()` y de esta forma cuando son iguales, realizar un `Intent` para abrir la `Activity` que deseas, recuerda que todas las `Activity` deben estar registradas en el `AndroidManifest.xml`

Se puede hacer uso del método `trim()` para eliminar los posibles espacios.

Para abrir otra `Activity` puedes realizarlo mediante un `Intent`:

```
if (profil.getId().toString().equals(response.trim())){
        //Abre otra Activity.
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Activity.this, OtraActivity.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

---

El error posterior:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.mathiastoledo.talkit/com.mathiastoledo.tal‌​kit.MainoRegistro}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String com.facebook.Profile.getId()' on a null object
>   reference

se genera ya que la variable `profil` tiene un valor `null`.

Comment: gracias! pero tengo un problema con eso

Comment: en mi DB tengo ya un id registrado, pero aun asi me manda al activity else .
         if (profil.getId().toString().equals(response)){
                    //Abre otra Activity.
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainoRegistro.this, MainActivity.class);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                } else {

                    Intent otro = new Intent(MainoRegistro.this, Registro.class);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(otro);
                }

Comment: y response tiene el id de facebook que comentas? si es así agrega el método .trim() como agrego en mi respuesta.

Comment: sisi, ahora que coloco el metodo .trim() se detiene la app y en el logcat me dice lo siguiente:  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mathiastoledo.talkit/com.mathiastoledo.talkit.MainoRegistro}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.facebook.Profile.getId()' on a null object reference

Comment: El error es que profil tiene valor null! asegura corregir eso.

Comment: En futuras ocasiones, por favor votar a cierre como duplicado de: http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/225/227