# Problema al escanear redes Wifi en Android

Tags: java, android

Estoy intentando escanear las redes WiFi disponibles. Solo necesito una lista con sus SSID, pero la aplicación se para cuando llega al `this.wifilist = this.wifiManager.getScanResults();` Os agradecería si me echais una manita, soy bastante noob programando. Gracias

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String ssid = "RasPi";
private WifiManager wifiManager;
private List<ScanResult> wifilist;
private ArrayList<String> idList = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
private ListView listView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    Log.d("TAG","empezando");

    detectWifi();




}
public void detectWifi(){
    this.wifiManager = (WifiManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    Log.d("TAG","antes de start");
    this.wifiManager.startScan();
    Log.d("TAG","despues del start");
    this.wifilist = this.wifiManager.getScanResults();


    for(int i=0;i<wifilist.size();i++) {
        Log.d("TAG","Antes del getScanResults");
        Log.d("TAG","Despues, antes de add a idList");
        idList.add(i,wifilist.toString());
    }

    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,idList);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

}
```

}

Comment: Es importante que cuando ocurra un error, revises el LogCat esto para no estar a ciegas buscando la causa de un problema que puede tener infinidad causas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agrega en tu `AndroidManifest.xml` los permisos:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Si únicamente deseas el SSID puedes obtenerlo de esta forma:

```
WifiInfo info = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo ();
String ssid =info.getSSID();
```

o de esta forma cuando ya tiene una lista de `ScanResult` :

```
List<ScanResult> wifilist = wifiManager.getScanResults();
String ssid = wifilist.get(<indice elemento>).SSID;
```

Por lo tanto si quieres almacenar todos los `SSID` en tu List, se realizaría de esta forma:

```
public void detectWifi(){
    wifiManager = (WifiManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    wifilist = this.wifiManager.getScanResults();
    String ssid ="";
    for(int i=0;i<wifilist.size();i++) {
        ssid = wifilist.get(i).SSID;
        idList.add(ssid);
        Log.d("detectWIFI", "SSID: " +ssid);
    }
}
```

#### ***Importante**: para que se muestren los SSID es importante habilitar los servicios de geolocalización.

Comment: Perfecto, gracias. Ahora para comparar las ssid con la que yo quiero como lo hago? el info.getSSID me devuelve una string con comillas así "RasPi" y cuando la comparo con mi ssid no me lo acepta porque no le puedo poner las comillas. ejemplo "RasPi"!=RasPi y siempre entra en el if(). Y si pongo `myssid=""Raspi"";`no me coge RasPi como String. :(

Comment: @wasous amigo la comparación de strings debe realizarse mediante equals(), por ejemplo   if(!ssid.equals("RasPi")){ ...... es por eso que entra al if siempre. si tienes más duda agrega tu código.https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52020/programa-no-me-detecta-null/52028#52028

Comment: Ya me funciona! Muchísimas gracias. Me siento un poco tonto después de preguntar lo de el if jaja.