# Problema al escanear Redes Wifi en Android Studio, no me muestra el SSID

Tags: java, android, android-studio, permisos

Estoy usando el siguiente código pero no me muestra el BSSID en la lista de las redes Wifi,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView lv;
WifiManager wifi;
String wifis[];
WifiScanReceiver wifiReciever;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    wifi=(WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    wifiReciever = new WifiScanReceiver();
    wifi.startScan();

    Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            wifi.startScan();
            Toast notificacion=Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Actualizacion de parametros",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            notificacion.show();
        }
    });    
}


protected void onPause(){
    unregisterReceiver(wifiReciever);
    super.onPause();
}

protected void onResume(){
    registerReceiver(wifiReciever, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
    super.onResume();
}


private class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent){

        WifiInfo nombre1 = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
        TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        name.setText(nombre1.getSSID());

        List<ScanResult> wifiScanList = wifi.getScanResults();
        wifis = new String[wifiScanList.size()];

             for (int i=0; i<wifiScanList.size(); i++){            
            wifis[i]=((wifiScanList.get(i)).toString());
        }

        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, wifis));
    }
}
```

Solo me muestra la lista a partir de 'capabilities'pero el nombre de la red no lo muestra. Solo usando:

```
WifiInfo nombre1 = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
name.setText(nombre1.getSSID());
```

Es que puedo mostrar en un TextView el nombre de la Red Wifi pero si no estoy conectada a ninguna red no me muestra el nombre.

Por otro lado, los permisos que declare en 'Android Manifest' son:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Comment: Tu problema es que sólo te muestra el nombre de la red en el Textview cuando estás conectada y cuando no lo estas no lo muestra?

Comment: Hola Heidi, Deseas el BSSID o los servicios SSID?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que deseas obtener son los SSID en la WLAN y los puedes determinar de esta forma:

```
 WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        List<ScanResult> wifilist = wifiManager.getScanResults();
        for(int i=0;i<wifilist.size();i++) {
            Log.d("detectWIFI", "SSID: " +  wifilist.get(i).SSID );
        }
```

En cuanto a lo que comentas:

> Es que puedo mostrar en un TextView el nombre de la Red Wifi pero si
>   no estoy conectada a ninguna red no me muestra el nombre.

Esto es obvio, por ejemplo como podrías las propiedades de una WLAN en la que no estas conectada!.

---

En esta pregunta puedes ver las formas de obtener el SSID:

[Problema al escanear redes Wifi en Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/70824/problema-al-escanear-redes-wifi-en-android/70841#70841)

Comment: Muchas gracias. Resolvi el problema. Ahora me surge un nuevo inconveniente...
Pruebo este mismo código en un tlf Android API 25 y no escanea las redes, en cambio con otros de menor API si.. AYUDAAAA!!!

Comment: @HeidiMedina , si tienes un dispositivo con API 25 los permisos se deben requerir manualmente.