# ¿Por qué tengo que tener acceso a la localización para buscar wifi?

Tags: android

Este código me deja listar las wifi pero con la localización activada. Estoy usando android 7.0. Creo que no debo de tener la ubicación activada para que el scan funcione, ¿o sí?

```
private WifiManager wifiManager;
private List<ScanResult> wifiList;
private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
private final int ACCESS = 10;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login2);

    btnwifi = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnWifi);
    txtInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wifi_info);

    btnwifi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Login2.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, ACCESS);
                }
            } else {
                MyWifiMethod();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case ACCESS:
            if (grantResults.length >= 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                MyWifiMethod();
            else
                Toast.makeText(Login2.this, "No tiene permisos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
}

private void MyWifiMethod()
{
    wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    registerReceiver(wifiScanReciever, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
    wifiManager.startScan();
}

private final BroadcastReceiver wifiScanReciever = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION))
        {
            wifiList = wifiManager.getScanResults();
            sb = new StringBuilder();

            sb.append("\n" + "numero de conexiones: " + wifiList.size() + "\n");
            for(int i = 0; i < wifiList.size(); i++)
            {
                sb.append(new Integer(i+1).toString() + ". ");
                sb.append("SSID " + (wifiList.get(i).SSID));
            }

            txtInfo.setText(sb);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Asumo que has probado sin tener activada la localización y falla.

Comment: Has hecho tú el código?

Comment: si...lo que no entiendo es que cuando le pongo en ves de acceder a ACCES_FINE_LOCATION ACCES_NETWORK_STATE me dice que no hay resultados...

Comment: Alvaro Montoro tu respuesta es si... no entiendo porque..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entiendo lo que deseas Alex, de hecho tu pregunta me llevo a editar mi respuesta a esta pregunta:

[Problema al escanear redes Wifi en Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/70824/problema-al-escanear-redes-wifi-en-android)

ya que **no es posible hasta el día de obtener la lista de `ScanResult`´s activos mediante [getScanResults()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getScanResults()) si no tienes activados los permisos de Geolocalización.**

En realidad esto se reporto hace tiempo como un  bug:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37060483

---

como opinión personal, me parece que esto es requerido ya que quien desea escanear la red, pudiera ser identificado :-P