# No se reciben escaneos WiFi al ejecutar startScan() en Android 8 con targetSdkVersion 26+

Tags: java, android

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación que utiliza los escaneos WiFi para funcionar. Utilizo el método `startScan()` de la clase `WifiManager` y tengo programado un `BroadcastReceiver` para que se me notifique cuando el escaneo ha terminado y ya se pueden recoger los resultados.

El código que tengo funciona perfectamente en Android 7 e inferiores, e incluso funciona en Android 8 si configuro el `targetSdkVersion` a 25 (Android 7) o inferior.

El problema surge cuando subo el `targetSdkVersion` a 26 y ejecuto la aplicación en Android 8 (concretamente en un Nexus 5X), y es que los escaneos WiFi dejan de ser recibidos. Por mucho que yo ejecute `startScan()` nunca obtengo resultados. Repito, si bajo el `targetSdkVersion`a 25, vuelvo a recibir los resultados sin problemas.

Leyendo la documentación oficial de Android, indica que a partir de Android 8 los esacneos se ejecutarán con mucha menos frecuencia, pero se entiende que deben funcionar de igual manera. Incluso en Android P esta llamada está obsoleta.

Entiendo que en Android P no podré utilizar este método, pero en Android 8 sí, y sin embargo no funciona.

Dejo la documentación de `startScan()` por si hiciera falta: [Documentación](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#startScan())

Alguien sabe el porqué de este comportamiento o a alguien le pasa lo mismo?

EDITO:

Este es el código que **inicia los escaneos**:

```
public boolean startScan() {
   WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
   if (!wm.isWifiEnabled()) {
     try {
       wm.setWifiEnabled(true);
     } catch (SecurityException e) {
       Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Error enabling wifi", e);
       return false;
     }
   }
   boolean started = wm.startScan();
   Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Scan started? " + started);
   return started;
}
```

Este es el `BroadcastReceiver` que recibe el resultado de los escaneos (y funciona excepto en Android 8 con targetSdkVersion 26+):

```
public class InOutWifiScanResultsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
   private static final String LOG_TAG = "ScanResults";

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     super.onReceive(context, intent); // Nunca entra aquí con Android 8 y targetSdkVersion 26+
     List<ScanResult> results = getWifiResults(context);
     Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Received results (" +  results.size() + " AP's)");
   }

   private static List<ScanResult> getWifiResults(Context context) {
      WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
      try {
        return wm.getScanResults();
      } catch (SecurityException e) {
        return new ArrayList<>();
      }
   }
}
```

En el `Manifest` tengo los siguientes permisos y el `BroadcastReceiver` declarado:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>

 <receiver
    android:name=".InOutWifiScanResultsReceiver"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS"/>
    </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

El permiso de localización se pide en `runtime` por lo que estoy seguro de que se permite, ya que soy yo el que hace los tests. También me he asegurado de que la localización esté activada (está en máxima precisión (gps + netword)).

El `BroadcastReceiver` parece que está declarado porque funciona si el targetSdkVersion es 25 o inferior. También he probado ponerle `android:exported="true"` por si tuviera algo que ver, pero parece ser que no.

Agradezco toda ayuda.

Comment: Por otra parte, me hubiera gustado poner las etiquetas android-wifi, android-8 y android-wifimanager

Comment: Cual es el código que estas tratando, porqu eno lo agregas? @MarcEstrada

Comment: No lo he agregado porque es código básico extraído de la documentación y que funciona en todos los dispositivos excepto en Android 8. Al llegar a casa os lo pongo, a ver si veis algo que yo no esté viendo. Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: ¿Tienes los permisos de geolocalización activados en ese dispositivo?  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/70824/problema-al-escanear-redes-wifi-en-android/70841#70841

Comment: Sí, los tengo, activados y concedidos, porque la app se basa en la localización. También tengo la Ubicación del móvil activada como sugieren otras respuestas de SO, pero tampoco funciona.

Comment: @Jorgesys nadie tiene idea de esto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En Android 8 o superior los BroadcastRecivers implícitos declarados vía Manifest no envían ni reciben información por motivos de rendimiento y consumo de batería, se trata de una optiización introducida en Android 8 y que intenta limitar los trabajos que se ejecutan en [segundo plano](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts).

Hay algunas excepciones a esto ([excecpciones](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions)), pero la acción android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS por desgracia no es una de esas excepciones, así que en Android 8+ no se pueden registrar el android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS vía Manifest ya que no se recibirá nada.

Esto ocurre cuando usamos targetSdkVersion=26 (Android 8 Oreo) o superior,pero si declarar en Gradle un targetSdkVersion=25 o inferior la optimización no se aplicaría y la app funcionaría como era esperado hasta hoy en día .

Para hacer que esta funcionalidad devuelva los resultados esperados en Android 8  con targetSdkVersion 26+ hay que registrar la acción en el contexto de la aplicación.

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction("android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS");
context.registerReceiver(new InOutWifiScanResultsReceiver(), intentFilter);
```

Lo único es que hay que ser cuidadosos con esto, ya que sólo funciona cuando la app está en primer plano y no cuando está detenida.

Saludos,