# El metódo ContainsAll() en Listas Android devuelve False

Tags: java, android, lista

Buenas Tardes, estoy desarrollando una App Android que debe tener el siguiente comportamiento en una de sus Activities:

-Hay una Lista de Articulos Principal (listaDetalle) y una Lista Secundaria (listaDetalleForSave).

Cuando la lista secundaria tenga al menos una aparición de cada elemento de la lista principal, un `TextView` debería cambiar de Color y valor de Texto, para ésto, elaboré un pequeño método `isComplete()` que realiza la comparación de la siguiente manera:

```
public boolean isComplete()
    {
        boolean res = false;

            if(listaDetalleForSave.containsAll(listaDetalle))
            {res = true;}

            return res;
    }
```

Sin Embargo, a pesar de que hay al menos una aparición de cada elemento de la lista 2 en la lista 1 (Lo corroboré en modo Debug), el metodo `containsAll`, me devuelve siempre Falso.

Tiendo a imaginarme que es porque los objetos en realidad no son iguales (Cambia el valor de uno de sus atributos).
Intenté sobreescribir el método equals de la clase pero no ha ayudado.

```
   @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        DetCFStock objeto = (DetCFStock) obj;

        if(this.getID() == objeto.getID())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
```

Me podrían ayudar con ésto?

Comment: relacionada -> https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225/c%C3%B3mo-comparar-correctamente-strings-en-java Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucionado. El método equals estaba dando false por comparar Strings con == cambié la comparación por, valga la redundancia, equals, y funcionó.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj)
{
    DetCFStock objeto = (DetCFStock) obj;

    if(this.getID().equals(objeto.getID()))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}
```