# Ayuda con un ejercicio donde implemento Do While

Tags: java

Buenas necesito ayuda el siguiente código no está haciendo la evaluación del `if` luego de preguntar su continuar vuelve al comienzo del bucle.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EjercicioCinco {

    public static void main(String[]args){

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean continuamos = true;
        int auxNota = 0;
        int i = 0;
        String respuesta;

        do {

            System.out.println("Ingrese la nota");

            int nota = sc.nextInt();

            auxNota += nota;

             i++;

            System.out.println("Continuamos?");

            respuesta = sc.nextLine();

            if (respuesta == "n") continuamos = false;

        }while(continuamos);

        System.out.println("El Promedio de notas es : "+(auxNota/i));

    }

}
```

Comment: Podrías sacar el if y hacer la pregunta directamente en el while

Answer (score 1):

Pienso tiene dos errores:

1- al comparar string, mirar esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225/c%C3%B3mo-comparar-correctamente-strings-en-java/) la cual cuenta con varias respuestas sobre comparar string.

2- despues de leer un entero por ejemplo, y despues querer leer un string tiene que limpiar el buffer(buscando pregunta que lo explica)

*bueno no la encontre, pero tiene que borrar el buffer, por ejemplo con `nombre_de_su_scanner.nextLine();` antes de tomar el string algun string pues si antes obtuvo un dato numerico "se queda" en el buffer `\n` `\\s\` o cualquier retorno lo que puede provocar que no le funcione bien, pues los metodos `nextInt();` o cualquier nextX, no consumen lo mencionado, salvo `.nextLine();` por ejemplo, asi que usamos esa llamada al metodo para limpiar el buffer del scanner*

---

ahora cambie *`respuesta == "n"` por `respuesta.equals("n")` y añada `sc.nextLine();` antes de `respuesta = sc.nextLine();`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EjercicioCinco {

    public static void main(String[]args){

   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean continuamos = true;
    int auxNota = 0;
    int i = 0;
    String respuesta;

    do {

        System.out.println("Ingrese la nota");

        int nota = sc.nextInt();

        auxNota += nota;

         i++;

        System.out.println("Continuamos?");
        
        sc.nextLine();
        respuesta = sc.nextLine();

        if (respuesta.equals("n")) continuamos = false;

    }while(continuamos);

    System.out.println("El Promedio de notas es : "+(auxNota/i));

    }

}
```

---

Test:

## <kbd>[Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/oclkBc)</kbd>

P.D: Si esta haciendo la evaluacion del `if` pero por lo mencionado en los puntos anteriores no hace lo que usted espera.