# Detectar idioma Android 4.0 y 7.0

Tags: java, android

Para una aplicación, con la intención de detectar cuándo está el dispositivo en español, he usado el siguiente `if`:

```
if(Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()=="es")
```

No obstante, aunque esto me ha funcionado en el emulador de Android Studio (7.0) cambiando el idioma del dispositivo desde los ajustes y abriendo la app en distintas situaciones, en el 4.0 no detecta el español de esta manera, por lo que siempre pasa por el `else`.

Por ello me gustaría saber si este método se puede usar con todas las versiones, si no es así cuál debería usar y en caso contrario qué es lo que falla para que unas veces funcione y otras no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cambia `if(Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()=="es")` por

```
if("es".equals(Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()))
```

Los `Strings` en Java no se deben comparar con `==`, sino con el método `equals`.

Deberías echar un ojo a [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225/c%C3%B3mo-comparar-correctamente-strings-en-java/365#365) para más información.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón. No obstante, si es así, ¿Por qué a veces funciona y otras no?

Comment: Es casualidad. El compilador reutiliza los huecos de memoria de Strings para mejorar el rendimiento, pero este comportamiento es arbitrario y no consistente entre diferentes equipos.