# Operador != no funciona como espero en Java

Tags: java

estoy tratando de resolver porque en mi función do-while al ejecucutarla dentro de mi programa, si escribo "Q" o "q" la ejecución continua en lugar de salir del bucle:

```
public void enroll() {
    // Get inside a loop, user hits Q to exit
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String course;      
    do {            
        System.out.print("Enter course to enroll (Q to quit): ");
        course = in.nextLine();
        courses = courses + "\n" + course;
        tuitionBalance = tuitionBalance + costOfCourse;         
    } while (course != "Q".toLowerCase());
    System.out.println("Enrolled in: " + courses);
    System.out.println("Tuition balance: " + tuitionBalance);
}
```

Gracias anticipadas por cualquier ayuda

Answer (score 4, accepted):

la comparación de cadenas se realiza mediante el método [equals()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object))

> [equals()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object))  Indica si algún otro objeto es "igual a" este.

Revisa esta pregunta:

[¿Cómo comparar correctamente Strings (y objetos) en Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225/c%C3%B3mo-comparar-correctamente-strings-y-objetos-en-java)

por lo tanto cambia tu comparación, y ya que quieres buscar cuando no son diferentes usa `!`  y para normalizar a minusculas usa el método [toLowerCase()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase()) :

```
...
} while (!course.toLowerCase().equals("q"));
...
```

de esta forma saldrá del bucle cuando la letra sea "Q" o "q".

---

De otra forma puedes usar:

**[equalsIgnoreCase()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-)** : Compara esta Cadena con otra Cadena, ignorando las consideraciones del caso. Dos cadenas se consideran mayúsculas y minúsculas si son de la misma longitud y los caracteres correspondientes en las dos cadenas son iguales a mayúsculas y minúsculas.

---

Para ambos métodos que anteriormente comente, es buena práctica hacer uso de  del método [trim()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) para eliminar los posibles espacios en los extremos de la cadena:

```
  ...
  } while (!course.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("q"));
  ...


  ...
  } while (!course.trim().equals("q"));
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Los tipos de datos `String` no se comparan con `!=`, sino con `nombreVariable.equals("Q")`

inténtalo para que veas.

Answer (score 0):

Con `equals` se comparan objetos **String** o cadenas, 
Para que sea igual es `nombreVariable.equals("Q");`
Para que sea diferente es `!nombreVariable.equals("Q");` con **!** al inicio

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer comparaciones de String se utiliza `equals()` y el operador `!=` compara referencia a objetos. Tu código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
public void enroll() {
    // Get inside a loop, user hits Q to exit
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String course;      
    do {            
        System.out.print("Enter course to enroll (Q to quit): ");
        course = in.nextLine();
        courses = courses + "\n" + course;
        tuitionBalance = tuitionBalance + costOfCourse;         
    } while (!course.toLowerCase().equals("q"));
    System.out.println("Enrolled in: " + courses);
    System.out.println("Tuition balance: " + tuitionBalance);
}
```

[Revisa esta pregunta de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

[Otra pregunta de SO Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225/c%C3%B3mo-comparar-correctamente-strings-y-objetos-en-java)