# Como preguntar si un String es diferente a otro?

Tags: javascript, string

Buenas ocupo saber como puedo preguntar si un `string` es diferente a otro, por ejemplo se que para pregunta si es igual a algo utilizo `equals`, pero mi duda es por ejemplo con un `int` puedo usar `!=` para decir que es diferente, ahora como puedo preguntar algo parecido para un `String`, se que no puedo usar variables como `==` ó `!=` para un `String`.

Comment: Tú pregunta es para javascript o para java?. agregaste la etiqueta javascript, pero la descripcion de tu pregunta pareciera que a punta hacia java.

Comment: Iba a decir lo mismo, me suena que es para el lenguaje Java en vez de JavaScript.

Comment: De paso leete este post [¿Cómo comparar correctamente Strings (y objetos) en Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/225/107347)

Comment: Y este tambien [Operador != no funciona como espero en Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/150006/107347)

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo comparar correctamente Strings (y objetos) en Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225/c%c3%b3mo-comparar-correctamente-strings-y-objetos-en-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sin utilizar los operadores `==` ó `!=` puedes comparar dos `strings` o saber si son distintos de la siguiente manera:

```
 //comparar
if(str1.equals(str2)){
     System.out.println("Iguales");
}
```

Puedes utilizar la forma anterior añadiendo `!`

```
 //distintos
if(!str1.equals(str2)){
     System.out.println("No iguales");
}
```

También si quieres puedes utilizar el método `compareTo()`

```
 //comparar
if(cadena1.compareTo(cadena2)==0){
    System.out.println("Iguales");
}

 //distintos
if(cadena1.compareTo(cadena2)!=0){
    System.out.println("No iguales");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que cuando las dos cadenas no sean iguales, trates de hacer algo. Puedes usar el mismo método `equals` algo así como:

```
//Entendí que es para Java
if(!tucadena.equals(otracadena)){
     System.out.println("Not equal");
}
```