# Android Studio - ¿Como cambiar de fragment por medio de código en una actividad de tipo Navigation Drawer?

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Mi problema es que intento abrir determinado fragment dependiendo del usuario que esté usando la aplicación, pero el código con el que intenté simplemente no funciona. 
.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

    private NavController nc, nc2;
    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    private NavigationView nv;
    private AppBarConfiguration abc;
    private EditText nombree;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        nv = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        nombree = findViewById(R.id.et_ciudad);

        abc = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_inicio, R.id.nav_perfil, R.id.nav_chat,
                R.id.nav_favoritos, R.id.nav_buscar,
                R.id.nav_configuracion, R.id.nav_ayuda)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        nc = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(nv, nc);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        switch(id){
            case R.id.nav_chat:
                break;
            case R.id.nav_perfil:
                String nombre = nombree.getText().toString();

                if(nombre == "Repartidor"){
                    fragment_contenedor_perfil_a fa = new fragment_contenedor_perfil_a();
                    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,fa).commit(); }
                else{
                    fragment_contenedor_perfil_b fb = new fragment_contenedor_perfil_b();
                    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,fb).commit(); }
                break;}
        return true;}}
```

.
Gracias por leer!

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te recomiendo que si tienes algo avanzado lo adjuntes en la pregunta para poder darte una respuesta de acuerdo a lo que necesitas. Revisa [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para más información. Saludos ;)

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda hermano. Voy a agregarlo para que sea más entendible!

Comment: @TomasMenniti revisando tu pregunta he visto cual es el problema, se debe a la forma en la cual tratas de realizar la comparación de la cadena.

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a tu código, tu layout `activity_main.xml` debe contener el FrameLayout con id `nav_host_fragment` que es donde se realizaría el reemplazo de los Fragments.

Pero noto un problema al tratar de obtener el usuario y realizar la comparación.

Recuerda como se realiza la comparación de Strings:

[Operador != no funciona como espero en Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/150003/operador-no-funciona-como-espero-en-java/150006#150006)

En este caso, la comparación de cadenas la puedes realizar usando los métodos [equals()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) o [equalsIgnoreCase()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-), realiza el siguiente cambio:

```
  ...
  ...
     case R.id.nav_perfil:
                    String nombre = nombree.getText().toString();

                    //*Incorrecto if(nombre == "Repartidor"){

                    if(nombre.equalsIgnoreCase("Repartidor")){

                        fragment_contenedor_perfil_a fa = new fragment_contenedor_perfil_a();
                        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,fa).commit(); }
                    else{
                        fragment_contenedor_perfil_b fb = new fragment_contenedor_perfil_b();
                        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,fb).commit(); }
                    break;
          }
 ...
 ...
```

Comment: Gracias Elena. Estoy algo confundido con tu respuesta en la parte en que mencionas que el setContentView debería contener el nav_host_fragment. 1er punto: "nav_host_fragment" es el nombre que por defecto asigna android studio a una vista de tipo "fragment" que viene en una activity llamada "content_main". En todo caso, no debería cambiar "activity_main" por "content_main"?. Agradecería que me aclares esta parte.

Comment: Perdon tal vez fue más información que posiblemente no sea necesaria, dentro de activity_main.xml debes tener nav_host_fragment que al parecer es así, solo realiza el cambio de la comparación a :  if(nombre.equalsIgnoreCase("Repartidor")){

Comment: Gracias. Me venis ayudando muy seguido. Como puedo votar tu respuesta como positiva??

Comment: Hola @TomasMenniti realiza el [tour] ahí se explica, saludos.