# ¿Porque mi condición no se evalúa como espero?

Tags: java, spring

Tengo en un Controlador el siguiente metodo, el cual evalua el genero de un usuario cuando va a registrarse en mi sitio.

```
if (user.getGender() != "other" && user.getGender() != "male" && user.getGender() != "female") {
            model.addAttribute("invalid_gender", 1);
            model.addAttribute(Constants.TITLE, REGISTER_TITLE);
            return "register";
        }
```

En mi formulario tengo unicamente 3 opciones para el genero, las cuales son

- Other
- Male
- Female

Si bien el texto tiene la primera letra de cada uno en mayúsculas, el *value* esta siempre en minúscula y así se guarda en la base de datos.

El problema es que aunque yo seleccione un genero del combobox, por alguna razon entra a mi *condicional if*. Si yo desde *inspeccionar elemento* modifico el value de los combobox, aun asi también me salta el error personalizado de *genero invalido* (esto es correcto, lo que no es correcto es que me salte cuando el genero es valido).

Sabiendo que con que una de las condiciones no se cumpla me debería de devolver **false** pero intrigado de porque esto no sucedia probe lo siguiente

```
System.out.println(true && false && false);
System.out.println(false && true && false);
System.out.println(false && false && true);
```

Y como era de esperar, todos devuelven ***false***, pero aun así se ejecuta el código de mi *if*.

Cabe aclarar que he logrado lo que queria de la siguiente forma

```
if (!(user.getGender().equals("other") || user.getGender().equals("male") || user.getGender().equals("female"))) {
            model.addAttribute("invalid_gender", 1);
            model.addAttribute(Constants.TITLE, REGISTER_TITLE);
            return "register";
        }
```

Pero, ¿que es lo sucede en la primera forma que siempre se evalúa como **true**?

Saludos y gracias.

Comment: La pregunta está bien planteada, pero es un duplicado de [¿Cómo comparar correctamente Strings (y objetos) en Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225/c%c3%b3mo-comparar-correctamente-strings-y-objetos-en-java)

Comment: No la habia visto @PabloLozano . Crees que para evitar confusiones o cualquier problema lo mejor sea eliminarla?

Comment: Puedes eliminarla, si quieres. Si no lo haces, se cerrará como duplicada (no resta reputación)