# Método en clase para comparar cadenas contenidas en un ArrayList

Tags: java

Lo que quisiera saber es cómo comprar dos cadenas, es decir...
Tengo el siguiente código:

```
 List<String> p;
 private class Lista {
    private String Lista() {
        p = new ArrayList<>();
        p.add("brócoli");
        p.add("círculo");
        p.add("célula");
        p.add("carátula");
        p.add("depósito");
        p.add("física");
        p.add("ábaco");
        p.add("azúcar");
        p.add("ámbar");
        p.add("ángel");
        p.add("César");
        p.add("césped");
        p.add("cádiz");
        p.add("éter");
        p.add("bebé");
        p.add("acción");
        p.add("avión");
        p.add("Jesús");
        p.add("país");
        p.add("papá");
        p.add("sofá");


        return null;
     }
}
```

Y quisiera comparar en otro método con un if, el método es el siguiente:

```
 private class Incorrecto {
    private String Incorrecto() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Es decir, si la palabra es igual a "bebé" es correcto, y cambiaría el textoen el `JLabel`.

---

Esta es la clase que traté de realizar:

```
 private class Incorrecto {
    private String Incorrecto() {
        if(p.equals("bebé")){
            coi.setText("¡Es correcto!");  <---Este es en el jlabel en el que se va a imprimir en el entorno gráfico y este método va dentro de un jbutton.
        } return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿ Deseas comparar todos los valores almacenados en el ArrayList p ?

Comment: Sí, para que me diga si es correcto o no cuando yo apriete un botón (jbutton)

Comment: Ok, un elemento que sea igual cambiaría el texto a "¡Es correcto!", agregué respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Si únicamente deseas cambiar el valor de `JLabel` tu método puede ser definido tipo `void`, este método recibiría los elementos contenidos en el ArrayList para ser comparados en un bucle, si alguno es igual (en este caso a "bebé", el texto mostrado en el `JLabel` sería "¡Es correcto!"

```
private class Incorrecto {

    private void Incorrecto(List p) {
        for(int i = 0; i<p.size();i++){
        //Obtiene valor de cadena en ArrayList.
        String cadena  = (String)p.get(i);
         if(cadena.equals("bebé")){
             //Si el contenido es igual cambia el texto en JLabel
            coi.setText("¡Es correcto!");             
          } 
        }
    }    
}
```

llamarías de esta forma el método:

```
   List  p = new ArrayList<>();
    p.add("brócoli");
    p.add("círculo");
    p.add("célula");
    p.add("carátula");
    p.add("depósito");
    p.add("física");
    p.add("ábaco");
    p.add("azúcar");
    p.add("ámbar");
    p.add("ángel");
    p.add("César");
    p.add("césped");
    p.add("cádiz");
    p.add("éter");
    p.add("bebé");
    p.add("acción");
    p.add("avión");
    p.add("Jesús");
    p.add("país");
    p.add("papá");
    p.add("sofá");


    Incorrecto incorrecto = new Incorrecto();
    incorrecto.Incorrecto(p);
```

---

Recuerda que la forma correcta para comparar cadenas es mediante el uso del método `equals()`

[¿Cómo comparar correctamente Strings (y objetos) en Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225/c%c3%b3mo-comparar-correctamente-strings-y-objetos-en-java)

Answer (score -1):

Ya probaste con el método equals() ?

> String1.equals(String2)

```
private String Incorrecto(List p, String cadena) {
for(int indice = 0; indice < p.size(); indice++) {
  if(p.get(indice).equals(cadena)) {
      return "Correcto";
 } else {
      return "Incorrecto";
 }
```

}
}

Es codigo no probado, adaptalo a tu codigo

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, ya probé con equals() pero no me da el resultado.

Comment: Puedes enseñarme el codigo de como lo usas? Porque con equals deberia ser mas que suficiente para lo que quieres hacer. Ten en cuenta que los 2 Strings deben ser totalmente iguales (No mayusculas, ni tildes), porque para eso se usa otro metodo donde no se tenga en cuenta por ejemplo, si un String esta en mayusculas y el otro no.

Comment: Te lo pongo en la siguiente respuesta.

Comment: Antes de comparar imprime p ya sea por consola o por un mensaje (JOptionPane)... Para ver que valor tiene. Y como recomendación utiliza Pastebin.com cuando quieras compartir algún código, allí se entiende mejor.

Comment: Mira creo que te falta algo mas de codigo.... debes recorrer p porque esta es una lista y obtener cada valor que tenga almacenado, esto lo puedes hacer con un for, a medida que vayas obteniendo sus valores entonces ahi si los comparas con equals. No puedes comparar una lista(p) con un String de la forma que lo estas haciendo.

Comment: Ese for lo debo meter con un entero? o cómo se metería ese for?

Comment: Actualice mi respuesta, buena suerte :)

Comment: Gracias y otra duda, si la cadena tiene acentos se usa igual el equals()?