# Problema que parece basico en java

Tags: java, url

Estoy iniciándome en java (aunque ya estoy haciendo programas mas avanzados con threads (aun no creados) o clases mas avanzadas), y estoy haciendo un programa que descargue un url leído y deje su contenido en un fichero.
Ese fichero tendrá que tener la extensión del url descargado, y si no hay fichero en la url, sera un html.
Para eso cuando leo la url saco la extensión del archivo de esta y, sino hay fichero, tiene que ser creado un html. El problema viene ahí, cuando creo un if que comprueba si hay extensión y, por ejemplo, con google.es la variable "extension" = ".es", pero no se porque nunca entra en el if.
He probado a printar lo que vale "extensión" y me sale .es, así que por lógica tendría que entrar, pero no. Hasta le he añadido que solo coja hasta el final del tamaño del texto para que no guarde nada extra y tampoco, no lo entiendo, "extensión" y el if son iguales así que hay algo que se me escapa.
Por eso digo en la descripción que parece un problema básico, la entrada de un if... muchas gracias de antemano.

[image: parte del programa donde esta el problema]

Comment: Aquí un buen sitio para aprender Java: http://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/javaya/

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. Por favor, pon el código relevante como texto, no como una captura de pantalla.

Comment: La comparación de String en Java es con .equals, no confundas con Javascript u otros lenguajes.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo comparar correctamente Strings (y objetos) en Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225/c%c3%b3mo-comparar-correctamente-strings-y-objetos-en-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para la comparación de String se debe usar equals, donde se compara la constante antes de la variable, para no incurrir en un nullPointerException, si lo haces de la siguiente manera te funciona perfecto saludos,

puedes usar iqualsIngnoreCase en caso que la url pueda esta en mayúsculas o minúsculas.

```
String url = "google.es";
    String extension = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("."),url.length());
    if(".es".equals(extension)){
        System.out.println("-----> "+extension);
    }
```