# Validar dos variables

Tags: android, condiciones

necesito ayuda, validar dos variable , una variable me la trae del sistema y la otra yo la asigno fija y estas se debe comparar y mostrar un mensaje pero no el codigo que tengo no me muestra error pero no me compara

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);


        Thread t = new Thread() {


            @Override
            public void run() {

                while (!isInterrupted()) {

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);  //1000ms = 1 sec

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                          @Override
                                          public void run() {

                                              TextView tdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                                              long date = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                              SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
                                              String dateString = sdf.format(date);
                                              tdate.setText(dateString);


                                              String dateInString2 = "2019";
                                              Date fecha = null;
                                              try {
                                                  fecha = sdf.parse(dateInString2);
                                              } catch (ParseException e) {
                                                  e.printStackTrace();
                                              }
                                              long dateInTimeStamp = fecha.getTime();

                                              if (dateString==dateInString2){
                                                  textView.setText("evento inicio");




                                              }



                                          }


                                      }

                        );

                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }
            };

        t.start();
        }


        public void button(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

        private void startActivities(Intent intent) {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estas comparando cadenas y esto es incorrecto:

```
   if (dateString==dateInString2){
       textView.setText("evento inicio");
   }
```

debe ser de esta forma usando el método `equals()` :

```
  if (dateString.equals(dateInString2)){
      textView.setText("evento inicio");
  }
```

revisa:

[¿Cómo comparar correctamente Strings (y objetos) en Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225/c%C3%B3mo-comparar-correctamente-strings-y-objetos-en-java/258#258)