# JAVA | Error al tomar valor booleano por Scanner

Tags: java

Pretendo tomar por `scanner` un *"sí"* o *"no"*, y si la comparación `grat == "si"` se cumple, debería tomar como `true`. Pero no funciona.

```
System.out.println("¿Envio gratuito? (si no)");
String grat = scan.nextLine();
boolean gratuito = (grat == "si");
System.out.println(gratuito);
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo comparar correctamente Strings (y objetos) en Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225/c%c3%b3mo-comparar-correctamente-strings-y-objetos-en-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En java, la comparación de `Strings` no debe realizarse mediante `==`

```
boolean gratuito = (grat == "si");
```

debes usar el método [**equals()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-):

```
boolean gratuito = (grat.equals("si"));
```

De hecho al parecer es un error común cuando iniciamos a programar en algunos lenguajes, en el caso de Java, te sugiero revisar:

[¿Cómo comparar correctamente Strings (y objetos) en Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225/c%c3%b3mo-comparar-correctamente-strings-y-objetos-en-java)

Answer (score 2):

Compañero, tienes un error muy simple, recuerda que para la comparación de cadenas (String) utilizamos `equals`, tu estas utilizando `==` como si fuera un entero.

```
  System.out.println("¿Envio gratuito? (si no)");
  String grat = scan.nextLine();
  boolean gratuito = (grat.equals("si"));
  System.out.println(gratuito);
```