# ¿Por que no imprime 4 true?

Tags: java

Tengo una pequeña duda, tengo el siguiente código

```
public static void main(String[] main) {
    String s1 = "Java";
    String s2 = "Java";

    StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
    sb1.append("Ja").append("va");

    System.out.println(s1 == s2);

    System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));

    System.out.println(sb1.toString() == s1);

    System.out.println(sb1.toString().equals(s1));

}
```

La salida es:

***true

true

false

true***

Mi duda es es esta línea:

```
System.out.println(sb1.toString() == s1);
```

¿Por qué esto no es igual? ¿Por qué no es true?

Comment: Te dejo este enlace que te servirá de mucha ayuda: https://www.campusmvp.es/recursos/post/java-comparacion-de-cadenas-literales-clases-repositorio-de-cadenas.aspx

Comment: Posible duplicado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225/c%C3%B3mo-comparar-correctamente-strings-y-objetos-en-java

Answer (score 4):

La siguiente línea :

```
System.out.println(sb1.toString() == s1);
```

Se está usando mal `==`, ya que al querer comparar dos objetos `String`, con `==`, no estás comparando su contenido, si no que estás comparando que ambas cadenas **sean el mismo objeto**.

Lo correcto es comparar con el método `equals()` o `equalsIgnoreCase()`

---

Ahora bien, la siguiente línea:

```
 System.out.println(s1 == s2);//funciona y devuelve lo esperado
```

Funciona correctamente, ya que el compilador de Java, al crear `s2`, ve que ya existe un objeto con el mismo valor, en este caso `s1`, y lo usa, por lo mismo en ese caso daría `true`, ya que hacen referencia al mismo objeto.

A diferencia de la línea que te da false, ya que al aplicar el método `toString()` a `s1`, se está creando una nueva instancia diferente a las anteriores.

Información extraída de [COMO COMPARAR STRING EN JAVA](https://programandoointentandolo.com/2013/10/como-comparar-string-en-java.html)