# Error de comparación en un if else

Tags: java, array, eclipse, condiciones

resulta que estoy haciendo una clase, y en un método tengo un if else dentro de un for:

```
            for(int i=0; i<usuariosProfes.length && sigue; i++) {

                if(usuariosProfes[i].obtenerEmail() == usuario.obtenerEmail()
                && usuariosProfes[i].obtenerContraseña() == usuario.obtenerContraseña()) {

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, email + " - " + contraseña);

                }else {

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos");
                    System.out.println(usuariosProfes[i].obtenerEmail() + usuario.obtenerEmail() +
                            usuariosProfes[i].obtenerContraseña()+ usuario.obtenerContraseña());
                    sigue = false;

                }

            }
```

Lo que ese bloque suelta es "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos". El problema no es el resto del método, porque literalmente, al imprimir los métodos en la consola ¡Los muestra exactamente iguales!
Porqué toma los datos ingresados como si fueran diferentes? Aclaro, los dos métodos imprimen resultados de tipo String, sino habría un error de compilación.

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: para que sirve el "&&" en `for(int i=0; i<usuariosProfes.length && sigue; i++)`

Comment: Sirve para detenerlo una vez que el boolean sigue se haga false, como dice el ejercicio. El boolean se hace false cuando pasa por el else, porque parece que es el else el que se está ejecutando!

Comment: Esto es un error muy común cuando iniciamos en el mundo de la programación,debes recordar que en el lenguaje Java se utiliza la función .equals() para comparar cadenas, NUNCA debería usarse el operador == , saludos. @Oto

Answer (score -1, accepted):

El problema es que estas comparando las cadenas de texto (String) con ==, pero en java para comparar cadenas de texto se usa la propiedad **equals()**.

Debes modificar tu código y dejarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
for(int i=0; i<usuariosProfes.length && sigue; i++) {

                if(usuariosProfes[i].obtenerEmail().equals(usuario.obtenerEmail()) 
                && usuariosProfes[i].obtenerContraseña().equals(usuario.obtenerContraseña())) {

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, email + " - " + contraseña);

                }else {

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos");
                    System.out.println(usuariosProfes[i].obtenerEmail() + usuario.obtenerEmail() +
                            usuariosProfes[i].obtenerContraseña()+ usuario.obtenerContraseña());
                    sigue = false;

                }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

te recomiendo utilizar `break;` en vez de la variable sigue

```
for(int i=0; i<usuariosProfes.length; i++) {

           if(usuariosProfes[i].obtenerEmail() == usuario.obtenerEmail() && usuariosProfes[i].obtenerContraseña() == usuario.obtenerContraseña()) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, email + " - " + contraseña);

            }else {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos");
                System.out.println(usuariosProfes[i].obtenerEmail() + usuario.obtenerEmail() +
                        usuariosProfes[i].obtenerContraseña()+ usuario.obtenerContraseña());
                break;

            }

        }
```

en el caso de que no quieras usar break utiliza un while

Comment: Hola, me recomendaron no usar `break;` ya que es causante de muchos bugs. De todas formas lo probé pero el resultado sigue siendo el mismo!

Comment: @oto este algoritmo solo te compara la primera posicion del usuariosProfes si llega a ser falso te saca y no seguiria comparando

Comment: @Oto *me recomendaron no usar `break;`, ya que es causante de muchos bugs...* No es del todo cierto, si la sentencia `break` ocasionara bugs, nunca se hubiese introducido al lenguaje. Con el `break` puedes romper el ciclo para evitar hacer iteraciones innecesarias y en algunas situaciones te ahorra usar variables booleanas. Siempre que alguien no te recomiende algo, debes decirle el "porque", así sabrás los verdaderos motivos.

Answer (score 0):

Revisa esta pregunta:

[¿Cómo comparar correctamente Strings (y objetos) en Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225/c%c3%b3mo-comparar-correctamente-strings-y-objetos-en-java/258#258)

> **En el lenguaje Java se utiliza la función** .equals() **para comparar
>   cadenas**, NUNCA debería usarse el operador == .

El problema se debe a que realizas una comparación incorrecta de cadenas, es incorrecto usar el operador `==` :

```
if(usuariosProfes[i].obtenerEmail() == usuario.obtenerEmail()
                && usuariosProfes[i].obtenerContraseña() == usuario.obtenerContraseña()) {
```

debes usar [**.equals()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) :

```
if(usuariosProfes[i].obtenerEmail().equals(usuario.obtenerEmail())
                && usuariosProfes[i].obtenerContraseña().equals(usuario.obtenerContraseña())) {
```