# ¿Por qué no funcionan los operadores de comparación de Java en Strings?

Tags: java

Estoy aprendiendo Java, intenté hacer algo simple(La secuencia Fibonacci).
Resulta que al intentar comparar una string con `==` o `!=` no funciona.
Hice un código aparte para ver si mi hipótesis era cierta, y resulta que tengo la razón.
¿Alguien sabe porqué sucede esto?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main{
    public static void main(String arg[]){
        String Tecla;
        Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
        Tecla = cin.nextLine();
        if(Tecla == "c"){
            System.out.println("Es [c]");
        }
    }
}
// No importa la tecla que de, no entra al if
```

Comment: Tu pregunta está duplicada y puedes encontrar una respuesta completa en este enlace: [¿Cómo comparar correctamente Strings (y objetos) en Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225/c%C3%B3mo-comparar-correctamente-strings-y-objetos-en-java). Me gustó mucho la respuesta de Carlos Lucero, explica como funciona todo.

Comment: Una respuesta corta de parte mía: La condición **siempre** dará `false` y esto se debe porque estás comparando direcciones de memoria. Ya que la variable `tecla` apunta hacia una dirección base de un objeto y la cadena `"c"` en realidad crea un objeto y por ende, se compara otra dirección base con lo que tenga `tecla`. En **conclusión:** Son direcciones de memoria diferentes, por eso da `false`.

Comment: Oh, ahora entiendo el porque.
Busque una pregunta similar a la mia, pero no encontré ninguna. Ahora veo que si está duplicada, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pruba eso o prueba con equals.Los String nunca se comparan con ==
import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class main{
    public static void main(String arg[]){
        String Tecla;
        Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
        Tecla = cin.nextLine();
        if(Tecla.compareToIgnoreCase("c")==0){
            System.out.println("Es [c]");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No es equals? Me parece lo tienes mal escrito

Comment: si se me a ido el dedo

Comment: Si me funcionó con los dos, gracias.

Comment: ¿Por qué nunca se compara con `==`? ¿Cual es la razón?

Comment: porque == compara objetos no contenido