# encontrar posición de String en un array multidimensional

Tags: java, array

Tengo este código sin embargo no logro identificar el problema.
Con enteros si funciona y con `String` no me da la posición (no funciona)

```
package com.mycompany.mavenproject1;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class NewMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     
     int fil=6,col=29,fi = 0,co = 0,posicion = 0;
     int cont=0;
     String nomb;
     
     String persona[][] = new String[6][29];
     Scanner no = new Scanner(System.in);
    
        System.out.println("ingresa el nombre");
        nomb = no.nextLine();
              
       persona[1][6]= "ed";
        cont=1;
        for (int i = 0; i < fil; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                if (persona[i][j]==nomb) {
                 posicion=cont;
                 fi=i;
                 co=j;
                    
                }
                cont++;
            }
        } 
         if(posicion>=1){
            System.out.println("Elemento encontrado en la posisión "+(posicion)+" del arreglo ");
            System.out.println("Se encuentra en la FILA "+(fi+1)+" COLUMNA "+(co+1));
         }else
            System.out.println("Elemento no encontrado");
    }
    
}
```

Comment: imprima System.out.println("Su nombre es: " + nomb); para ver que registro

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo comparar correctamente Strings (y objetos) en Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225/c%c3%b3mo-comparar-correctamente-strings-y-objetos-en-java)

Answer (score 0):

Para comparar `string` debes usar `.equals()`, pues el comparador `==` solo es para valores de tipo numérico.

Te paso el link de una pagina con un ejemplo https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/compare-two-strings-in-java/

Y otra donde se explica por se usa `equals` en vez de `==` https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-equals