# Misma estructura lógica en c# y java, distinto resultado

Tags: java, c#

estoy tratando de hacer un proyecto bastante simple, pero no entiendo porque me funciona mal en java. Es un do while que se repite si no ingreso gato, perro o conejo. En c# sale del bucle cuando ingreso perro, gato o conejo. En java, no, sigue repitiendo el bucle aunque ingrese gato, perro o conejo.

[image: Do while en c# y en java]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que Tenes acá, es que el operador != no es lo mismo en java que en c#

En c#, el operador hace los descripto [aca](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/equality-operators#inequality-operator-). En c#, los operadores hacen diferentes cosas, dependiendo el tipo de dato con el que están tratando. En este caso, como son strings, hace una comparación carácter a carácter, por lo tanto sirve para comparar strings.

También, podrías usar String.Compare(), la cual tiene mas opciones para hacer la comparación...

En java, como vemos en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/226/324), los operadores funcionan de otra forma.

Entonces en java, si estas obligado a usar equals para comparar.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar el

```
.equals("valor_a_comparar")
```

Comment: OP esta pidiendo una explicacion. Aca no le explicas nada.. considera mirar [answer] y dar una respuesta que explique el porque de las cosas...