# Setear un imageView en un formulario dependiendo del valor de un Spinner?

Tags: java, android

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo tres valores en el spinner "Pequeño", "Mediano" y "Grande" y cada uno debe ser representado por un ícono de rata, gato y caballo respectivamente. Los valores del spinner son un String, "Tamano". La pregunta es como puedo capturar el valor que toma el spinner para luego setear un ícono. La variable no aparece como un TextView (estoy en Android Studio) sino que solamente debiera aparecer la imagen...

Les comparto un ejemplo de la pantalla de la app.

Answer (score 1):

La variable `tamano` es una variable tipo String, no va a cambiar la imagen en el `ImageView` ya que la comparación se debe de realizar con la función `.equals()` en lugar del operador `==` , te sugiero revisar:

[¿Cómo comparar correctamente Strings (y objetos) en Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225/c%C3%B3mo-comparar-correctamente-strings-y-objetos-en-java/258#258)

Pero en este caso puedes simplificar el código para que revisa solo una vez el valor de "tamano" y realice la comparación usando una estructura "if - else if":

```
if(tamano.equals("Mediana")){
...
}else if(tamano.equals("Grande")){
...
}else if(tamano.equals("Pequeña")){
...
}
```