# Comparo dos String iguales en java y la condición devuelve "false"

Tags: java

Estoy desarollando un programa de mecanografía y a la hora de hacer el login, al cojer el valor/texto de un textField con el nombre del usaurio y compararlo con un atributo de un objeto Usuario (con nombre y contraseña), este me salta el if y literalmente las dos String son iguales.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). PD: ya que `String` es una clase, los objetos de esa clase deben ser comparados usando el método [`Object.equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)).

Answer (score 0):

No te funciona porque realmente estas comparando los objetos por así decirlo. Aunque tengas el mismo contenido en los dos objetos string no dejan de ser objetos diferentes. Para comparar el contenido y conseguir el resultado que necesitas tienes que usar el metodo `equals()`:

```
 String cadena1 = new String("Hola");
 String cadena2 = new String("Hola");
 if (cadena1.equals(cadena2))
 {
    ...
 }
```

Comment: Muchas gracais por la explicacion, ya me funciona, GRACIAS!!! <3

Comment: @Yorye si la respuesta te ha sido útil, en vez de usar los comentarios para dar las gracias, márcala como "respuesta aceptada" en el lado izquierdo de la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Para comparar objetos se utiliza el metodo `equal` y para los datos de tipo primitivo si se utiliza `==` intenta utilizando

```
    String usuarioTextFiel= "kkss";

    String usuario = "dd";
    
    if(usuario.equals(usuarioTextFiel)) {
        
    }
```

[Aqui puedes ver una respuesta a una pregunta similar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225/c%C3%B3mo-comparar-correctamente-strings-y-objetos-en-java)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias <3