# Java - Comparar dos variables enum

Tags: java, variables, enum

Estoy realizando un proyecto y tengo unas dudas en el código.

Tengo que comparar las dos variables y mostrar en pantalla el valor obtenido.

Pienso que el código es erróneo adaptándome a lo que tengo que realizar.

```
public class PROGRAMA {

    public enum Razas { 
        
        MASTIN, TERRIER, BULLDOG, PEKINES, CANICHE, GALGO;
        
    }
    
    public static void main (String[] args){
       
        Razas var1 = Razas.GALGO;
        Razas var2 = Razas.MASTIN;
        
       if (var1 == Razas.GALGO);
       if (var2 == Razas.MASTIN);
       
       System.out.println(var1==var2);
        
    }
    
}
```

*El output que recibo es el siguiente:*

```
false

BUILD SUCCESS

Total time:  0.500 s
Finished at: 2022-11-15T19:06:27+01:00
```

**EDIT**: Actualizado el código.

He borrado lo siguiente del código:

- if (var1 == Razas.GALGO);
- if (var2 == Razas.MASTIN);

*El output que recibo es el siguiente:*

```
false

BUILD SUCCESS

Total time:  0.484 s
Finished at: 2022-11-15T19:18:19+01:00
```

**Al comparar las dos variables, me da false, ya que no son la misma raza, si no me equivoco el objetivo que me piden esta resuelto.**

Comment: Cuál es la intención de los `if (varN == Razas.ALGUNACOSA);` ?

Comment: Hola, estoy pensando que los `if (varN == Razas.ALGUNACOSA);` no tienen mucha función en este código para lo que busco. Mi objetivo es mostrar en pantalla el valor obtenido de comparar ambas variables. En este caso, eliminando los `if (varN == Razas.ALGUNACOSA);` me quedaría el código muy pequeño y eso me da mala espina, pienso que lo estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: La función del código no es quedar grande o pequeño ;) La idea es decirle a la máquina qué hacer. Así pues, qué pasa si los quitas y corres el código? Qué pasa si los dejas y corres el código? En la sintaxis de Java, qué crees que significa eso? Recuerda [edit] la pregunta y aclarar todo lo que te comenten acá, además de los resultados de lo que vayas probando, etc.

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus comentarios, seguiré probando y  ejecutando el código. Java me resulta complicado al principio pero me gusta. Un saludo Alfabravo!

Answer (score 1):

Estas comparando objetos por lo que usar comparadores == directamente es incorrecto, podes usar el método heredado de los objetos equals() y te dará el resultado correcto.

```
System.out.println(var1.equals(Razas.GALGO));
System.out.println(var2.equals(Razas.MASTIN));
```

Existen algunos objetos como Integer en donde pueden usarse comparadores, pero si por algún motivo comparar dos objetos no te funciona podes usar equals. Al crear clases incluso podes sobrescribir este método para comparar objetos del tipo que hayas creado.

Comment: Gracias por tu aportación! Me ha ayudado mucho.

Answer (score 1):

Estas realizando la comparación de dos variables tipo `String` usando el operador ==, por esa razón no obtienes el valor deseado.

revisa:

**[¿Cómo comparar correctamente Strings (y objetos) en Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225/c%c3%b3mo-comparar-correctamente-strings-y-objetos-en-java)**

La comparación debería realizarse de esta forma:

```
if (var1.equals(Razas.GALGO));
if (var2.equals(Razas.MASTIN));
```

---

```
public class PROGRAMA {

    public enum Razas { 
        
        MASTIN, TERRIER, BULLDOG, PEKINES, CANICHE, GALGO;
        
    }
    
    public static void main (String[] args){
       
        Razas var1 = Razas.GALGO;
        Razas var2 = Razas.MASTIN;
        
       if (var1.equals(Razas.GALGO));
       if (var2.equals(Razas.MASTIN));
       
       System.out.println(var1.equals(var2));
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, me ha ayudado mucho!