# Uso correcto de la variable string

Tags: java

> Luego de modificar la variable string con un Scanner quiero validarla con if pero al hacerlo no se refleja. se que lo estoy haciendo bien ya que la imprimo con un sout me sale que se modifico

```
Scanner teclado2 = new Scanner (System.in);

 String nacionalidad="";

System.out.println("ingrese su pais\n");

nacionalidad = teclado2.next();

if (nacionalidad == "colombia" || nacionalidad == "Colombia") {System.out.println("Tienes la nacionalidad correcta\n");}
    else {System.out.println("No eres colombiano");}
```

> Suponiendo que el usuario escrbie que es de colombia esto aun asi daria el else y no el if

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo comparar correctamente Strings (y objetos) en Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225/c%c3%b3mo-comparar-correctamente-strings-y-objetos-en-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En Java debes usar debes usar [`equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) o [`equalsIgnoreCase()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)) para comparar cadenas.

Aquí conviene usar `equalsIgnoreCase()`, así evitas el `OR` y pasa sin importar cómo esté escrito: `ColoMbia, COLOMBIA, cOLOMBIA`, etc... :

> **`equalsIgnoreCase()`**
>
> Compara este `String` con otro `String`, ignorando las consideraciones
> de mayúsculas y minúsculas. Dos cadenas se consideran iguales
> ignorando mayúsculas y minúsculas si tienen la misma longitud y los
> caracteres correspondientes en las dos cadenas son iguales ignorando
> mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Por ejemplo:

```
if ( nacionalidad.equalsIgnoreCase("colombia") )
{
    System.out.println("Tienes la nacionalidad correcta\n");
}
else 
{
    System.out.println("No eres colombiano");
}
```

O, si quieres, puedes simplificar con un ternario:

```
String s=( nacionalidad.equalsIgnoreCase("colombia") ) ? 
"Tienes la nacionalidad correcta\n" : "No eres colombiano\n";
System.out.println(s);
```

O bien directamente:

```
System.out.println(nacionalidad.equalsIgnoreCase("colombia")  ? 
"Tienes la nacionalidad correcta\n" : "No eres colombiano\n");
```