# Problema con condición if

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un programa para un ejercicio que se basa en pedir un archivo txt y escribir los resultados en un archivo de salida. El archivo contiene descripciones y sus correspondientes cadenas de adn, el método que pongo a continuación es en el que tengo el problema, concretamente en el if final que dice si es proteína o no, las cadenas están ya divididas y guardadas en un array llamado `listaCodones`
Lo que quiero es que si el valor cero del array `listaCodones` coincide con la palabra (ATG) diga que si es proteína y si no lo contrario. El problema es que siempre me dice que no es proteína como si el array estuviese vacío, pero no es así porque he comprobado que tiene los valores en el formato correcto. Pongo el metodo entero:

````
public static void procesarFichero(Scanner leerFichero, PrintStream escribirFichero) throws FileNotFoundException {        
      int[] contador = new int[5];
      double[] porcentajes = new double[contador.length];
      String nucleotidos = null;
      double masaTotal = 0;
      double[] masas = {135.128, 111.103, 151.128, 125.107, 100.000};
      while (leerFichero.hasNextLine()) {
         String descripcion  = leerFichero.nextLine();
         nucleotidos  = leerFichero.nextLine();         
         nucleotidos = nucleotidos.toUpperCase();
         contador = new int[5];
         char[] letras = {'A', 'C', 'G', 'T', '-'};
         for (int i = 0; i < nucleotidos.length(); i++) {
            char letra = nucleotidos.charAt(i);
            for (int indice = 0; indice < letras.length; indice++) {
               if (letra == letras[indice]) {
                  contador[indice]++;
               }
            }
         }
         escribirFichero.println("Descripción: " + descripcion);
         escribirFichero.println("Nucleótidos: " + nucleotidos);
         nucleotidos = nucleotidos.replaceAll("-", "");
         int numCodones = nucleotidos.length() / CODON;
         String[] listaCodones = new String[numCodones];
         for (int i = 0; i < numCodones; i++) {
            listaCodones[i] = nucleotidos.substring(i * CODON, i * CODON + CODON); 
         }        
         masaTotal = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < contador.length; i++) {
            masaTotal += contador[i] * masas[i];
         }         
         for (int i = 0; i < contador.length; i++) {
            porcentajes[i] = (contador[i] * masas[i]) / masaTotal * 100;
            porcentajes[i] = Math.round(porcentajes[i] * 10.0) / 10.0;
         }       
         masaTotal = Math.round(masaTotal * 10.0) / 10.0;
         escribirFichero.println("Contadores: " + Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOfRange(contador, 0, contador.length - 1)));
         escribirFichero.println("Masa (%): " + Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOfRange(porcentajes, 0, porcentajes.length - 1)) + " de " + masaTotal); 
         escribirFichero.println("Lista Codones: " + Arrays.toString(listaCodones));
         if (listaCodones[0] == "ATG") {
            escribirFichero.println("Es proteína: SI");
         } else {
            escribirFichero.println("Es proteína: NO");
         }  
         escribirFichero.println();
      }
      leerFichero.close();
      escribirFichero.close();
   }```  
Gracias por la ayuda y cualquier duda, preguntad.
````

Comment: En java las cadenas de texto se comparan con la función `equals`.    `"cadena".equals("cadena")`

Comment: @Lobos Tienes razón, fallo grave el mío.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu array listaCodones contiene elementos de tipo String por lo tanto la comparación es incorrecta usando  `==`, debes realizar la comparación usando el método `equals()` :

```
    //if (listaCodones[0] == "ATG") {
     if (listaCodones[0].equals("ATG")) {
        escribirFichero.println("Es proteína: SI");
     } else {
        escribirFichero.println("Es proteína: NO");
     }
```

revisa:

[¿Cómo comparar correctamente Strings (y objetos) en Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225/c%c3%b3mo-comparar-correctamente-strings-y-objetos-en-java/41581#41581)

Comment: Gracias, a veces me obceco tanto con algo que paso por alto lo obvio en este caso que al ser de tipo String se usa otro comparador.