# metodo en java que regrese la posicion en el array del objeto en cuestion

Tags: java, array, metodos

tengo un codigo el cual se encarga de añadir objetos dentro de una arraylist y que con esos objetos del array se encarga de realizar varias operaciones, entre ellas una es borrar un objeto de la arraylist, para ello tengo el siguiente case de un switch:

```
case 2:
                    tamaño = Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce tamaño"));
                    aerodinamica = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce aerodinamica(mucho,media,poco)");
                    var eliminar = cocheAdmin.eliminarcocheCarrera(cochesCarrera, tamaño, aerodinamica);
                    if (eliminar == "El coche no existe"){
                        System.out.println(eliminar);
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println(eliminar.getClass());
                        cochesCarrera.remove(eliminar);
                    }
                    break;
```

Este metodo recopila datos para poder saber que objeto borrar a la hora de llamar al metodo 'eliminarcocheCarrera' que tiene el siguiente codigo:

```
public Object eliminarcocheCarrera(ArrayList cochesCarrera, float tama, String aero){
        for (int x = 0; x < cochesCarrera.size();x++){
            System.out.println(cochesCarrera.get(x)); 
            if (((cocheCarrera) cochesCarrera.get(x)).getAerodinamica() == aero && ((coche) cochesCarrera.get(x)).getTamano() == tama){
                return x;
            }
        }
            return "El coche no existe";
    }
```

Mi problema con todo esto es que yo quiero que este metodo retorne en el caso de que coincida con los parametros introducidos anteriormente,la posicion en el array del objeto en cuestion, esto lo he intentado ya de varias formas y no me ha funcionado ninguna:

1º Pasarle el arraylist y pensar que no era necesario que lo retorne ya que es el mismo array (No era el mismo array ya que al pasarle un array a un metodo este hace un duplicado y si haces cambios en el array del metodo el array de fuera no se actualiza junto con estos

2º Intentando retornar el array del metodo o en su defecto el indice en el que se encuentra el objeto en concrep, tampoco me ha funcionado devido a que el metodo si lo pongo de tipo int para que devuelva el indice, luego no le puedo pedir que retorne un mensaje de error, y en el caso de que devuelva un entero ejemplo 404 y este lo procese con otro if como un codigo de error no podria introducir indices en el array hasta el numero 404

Espero vuestra ayuda muchas gracias de antemano;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cosas que mirar:

- Si pasas un objeto como parámetro a un método en Java, lo que se le pasa es un duplicado **del puntero al objeto**, pero el objeto no se duplica. Imagina tener una lista con un millón de elementos, no tendría sentido duplicar la lista sólo para buscar un elemento. Por tanto, cualquier modificación que hagas a la lista queda reflejada fuera del método.
- Llamas al método `eliminar...` pero no eliminas nada, sólo buscas. Procura ser consistente con los nombres, te ahorrarás problemas cuando leas el código.
- Estás devolviendo `Object`, lo que generalmente no es una buena idea. Mi propuesta sería devolver un int: el índice del elemento borrado o -1, en caso de no encontrar nada que borrar. Esto sería consistente con el comportamiendo de métodos como `List.indexOf`.
- Estás comparando Strings usando `==`, [lo que no es correcto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225/c%C3%B3mo-comparar-correctamente-strings-y-objetos-en-java)
- Si vas a insertar y borrar elementos de una lista, ArrayList no es la mejor implementación, ya que borrar es una operación costosa. Te recomiendo usar LinkedList.
- Evita usar `float`. Java está pensando para usar `double` a menos que tengas problemas de memoria.
- Usa genéricos, te ahorrarás tener que hacer *casting*.

De este modo, el método para borrar debería ser algo así:

```
public int eliminarCoche(List<CocheCarrera> cochesCarrera, double tama, String aero){
    for (int x = 0; x < cochesCarrera.size(); x++){
        var coche = cochesCarrera.get(x);
        if (coche.getAerodinamica().equals(aero) &&
               (coche.getTamano() == tama) {
            cochesCarrera.remove(x);
            return x;
        }
    }
        return -1;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya te digo llevaba varios dias intentandolo y tenia un lio increible, corregido gracias;

Comment: Hola @Pablo, tengo una pregunta, porque usas "**var coche**" en lugar de "**CocheCarrera coche**", es solo para "ahorrar" escritura?.

Comment: @MarcePuente Sí, Java permite usar `var`al crear variables locales si puede inferir el tipo de manera trivial, como es este caso

Comment: Gracias maestro!!!!